# How to loop over specifc ids in a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, statistics

I have a csv file:

```
ids    year    mean
1      2000    200
2      2000    199
3      2000    193
4      2000    189
1      2001    205
2      2001    197
3      2001    197
4      2001    196
.
.
.
4      2016    212
```

I would like to loop over each individual `id` to calculate the person coefficient for each of them and put them in an individual list.
How can I do that?

I tried something that took forever and never worked:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

path = 'C:/path/'
#%%
df = pd.read_csv(path + 'mycsvfile.csv')

res = []
for i in range(df['id'].min(), df['id'].max()):
    x = stats.pearsonr(df['year'], df['mean'])
    res.append(x)

df = pd.DataFrame(res)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in

```
for i in range(df['id'].min(), df['id'].max()):
    x = stats.pearsonr(df['year'], df['mean'])
    res.append(x)
```

you have `i`, which is never used in for loop body, so you in fact does compute very same thing again and again.
What you need is groupby, consider following simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,3,3],'x':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'y':[1,2,4,3,5,6]})
out = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda data:stats.pearsonr(data['x'],data['y']))
print(out)
```

output

```
id
1     (1.0, 1.0)
2    (-1.0, 1.0)
3     (1.0, 1.0)
dtype: object
```

Explanation: [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) id, then apply Pearson's R computing for each group.